# Juntar duas consultas SQL SERVER em duas colunas sem repetições

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Preciso juntar o resultado de 2 SELECTS em uma mesma consulta, sendo que cada resultado retorna uma coluna, exibir um só resultado com as 2 colunas lado a lado, sem repetição.

Exemplo:

`SELECT A.VALUE AS pergunta_id FROM STRING_SPLIT('1,2,3,4', ',') A;`

`SELECT B.value AS resposta FROM STRING_SPLIT('R1,R2,R3,R4', ',') B;`

Comment: no `sql-server` se usar `UNION` vai remover as repetições, só irá manter tudo se usar `UNION ALL`, por isso não precisa de lógica adicional ai. Agora se os valores de cada query em separado tiverem valores duplicados, precisa fazer um `DISTINCT` em cada uma ou ao final

Comment: UNION junta tudo em uma coluna só, e não 2 colunas diferentes

Comment: entendi, nesse caso precisa por tudo no mesmo select então, mas não consegue fazer um "distinct entre colunas", só na mesma coluna

Answer (score 0):

Experimente utilizar o operador *Apply* para ver se é obtido o resultado esperado:

```
SELECT A.VALUE AS pergunta_id, B.value AS resposta
FROM STRING_SPLIT('1,2,3,4', ',') A
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT('R1,R2,R3,R4', ',') B
```

Espero que ajude